# Why is there in the while cycle after the scanf a -1?

Tags: c

I don't know why is there a >-1 after the scanf()!

```
while(scanf("%f %f %f %f", &x1,&x2,&y1,&y2)>-1 && (x1!=0 && x2!=0 && y1!=0 && y2!=0) )
{
   x=x1/x2;
   y=y1/y2;
```

Comment: Please read about [what `scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return).

Comment: It is checking if the return value of scanf is non-negative.

Comment: Sidenote: this code seems questionable. Proper code would check for complete success `== 4`, not for partial success `>-1`.

Comment: @user694733 That's **not** a sidenote. You're just being modest, that's actually one of the critical part.

Comment: `scanf` return a negative value if end of input or read error occur. So the `>-1` simple says: stop the loop on EOF or read error.

Comment: @SouravGhosh As we don't know what the code is doing we can't know if the number of matched items is critical/important

Comment: @4386427 Considering that the values are used immediately as part of the loop condition, and that those values will be indeterminate if `scanf` doesn't read them all, that's highly relevant. Especially since floating point values *can* have trap-values leading to UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude they may have been initialized before the loop. we don't know and we don't what happens in the loop before the next `scanf`

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and provide sample input. Also please explain each identifier, each called function, each operator. Let us know what you thought while programming this. Without that information, your question cannot be answered an should be closed as "Why code fails?" question without an MCVE.

Comment: `scanf("%f %f %f %f", &x1,&x2,&y1,&y2)>-1` is weak code.  `scanf("%f %f %f %f", &x1,&x2,&y1,&y2) == 4` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If successful, scanf returns the number of arguments successfully assigned.
If a failure in MATCHING occurs before the first argument is assigned, scanf returns 0 and 
if INPUT failure occurs before the first argument is assigned, EOF is returned.
And now, the answer to your question: EOF expands to -1, so your while is something like while("no input error in scanf()" &&....).